# How can i set a dot in any place in textbox for double field

Tags: wpf

I have a textbox

```
Text="{Binding Object.Area, StringFormat={}{0:F2}, Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
```

Area is double

When i entering a number in textbox, i must move cursor to right to fractional part of a number. 
How can I set a dot in any place of textbox?

Comment: Use Delay= 200 that way you will be able to add a decimal pointer

Comment: when i enter a digits, a dot is already present in the field. At the left side of a cursor. i want to put it myself)

Comment: I think that you should use the attached property because this topic is about to extend the functionality of the textbox.